Converting HurwitzZeta function to PolyGamma function
A generalization produces a result in terms of Zeta[s,a] function, which can be converted to PolyGamma[s-1,a] using the relationship
  Zeta[s_,a_]:=(-1)^s /(s-1)! PolyGamma[s-1,a]

My question is what code is needed to make the generalization automatically produce a result in terms of the polygamma?
Thank you
GPT gave the following code
     ZetaToPolyGamma[s_, z_] := Module[{n = s - 1}, 
     If[IntegerQ[n] && 
     n >= 0, (-1)^(n + 1) Factorial[n] PolyGamma[n, z], 
     "Conversion valid only for s = n + 1 where n is a non-negative integer"]];

which is useful for only manual conversion.

When you have an expression expr, you can substitute with conditions:
expr /. (Zeta | HurwitzZeta)[s_Integer /; s >= 2, a_] -> (-1)^s PolyGamma[s-1,a]/(s-1)!

Example:
expr = HurwitzZeta[5, 7]
(*    HurwitzZeta[5, 7]    *)

expr /. (Zeta | HurwitzZeta)[s_Integer /; s >= 2, a_] -> (-1)^s PolyGamma[s - 1, a]/(s - 1)!
(*    -(1/24) PolyGamma[4, 7]    *)


thank you so much

It should be Zeta in your code instead of hurwitzZeta.

@AliShadhar I don't think it makes a difference if Zeta or HurwitzZeta are used here. But please don't edit other people's answers!

When I used your code it didn't work and I edited it, it worked. It is not a big deal and I did it for a good reason. Test your code for any formula that produces a result in terms of HurwitzZeta and see if your code works.

@AliShadhar I've added an example and made it use Zeta or HurwitzZeta indeterminately.
